# Multi-dimensional Dirichlet-Dini criterion for Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mathbb I^d$ be the $d$-dimensional unit cube, and $f\in L^1(\mathbb I^d)$. Further let $x\in\mathbb I^d$ and assume that (some representative of) $f$ is differentiable at $x=(x_1,\dotsc, x_d)$ (or, if needed, in some neighborhood of $x$). Is it true that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m_1\leq n,\dotsc,m_d\leq n} \hat f_{m_1,\dotsc, m_k} e^{2\pi i (m_1x_1+\cdots m_d x_d)}=f(x) \qquad ?$$

For $d=1$, this is the classical Dirichlet(–Dini) criterion. For $d\geq 2$ it amounts to say that the $\ell^\infty$-Fourier partial sum $\sigma^\infty_n(f)$ converges to $f$ as $n\to\infty$ at every differentiability of $f$.

I would be interested in a reference for this statement, or (if false) in a counterexample.

Comment: The natural generalization of the Dini criterion needs higher differentiability. But Dini is not necessary so I don't know if there is a counterexample of convergence when $f$ has 1st derivatives.

Comment: @reuns hello! Thank you for your comment. Could you point me to a peer-reviewed reference with a complete proof under the assumption of higher differentiability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the multidimensional case the condition for a continuous function $f$ with the modulus of continuity $\omega(t)$ to have pointwise Pringsheim convergence it is enough that $\omega(t)\log^d\frac1t\to0$ then $t\to0+$. See referencies in the review B.I. Golubov, [*Multiple series and Fourier integrals*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01305756).

Comment: Thank you very much. That's more on Fourier series convergence than I could hope for.